# Android, testing a flow which involves other applications

Tags: android, testing, cross-application

I am testing an Android application using Instrumentation, Espresso and Robotium. The flow I need to test is the following:

1. typing email in a EditTextView
2. press confirm button
3. receive an email
4. click in the link received in the email to confirm the address

Now, everything is fine till the step 4, at that point I have no idea on how to open the Email application to click the link, is there a way to do it, or to mock it eventually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solution is to use [uiautomator](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html#UIAutomator) for this. It has everything you need to open email app and click the link.